# Unhandled exception when using opencv HOG descriptor compute function with OpenCL

Tags: opencv, gpu, opencl, descriptor

I've recently been looking into using OpenCL to reduce a bottleneck in our application, which is a call to cv::HOGDescriptor::compute(). Using the OpenCL version seems to be a simple case of using UMat instead of Mat and I've already had some success with the following:

```
// Replaced the following...
// _descriptor_calculator.compute(image, descriptor_flat);
// with...
cv::UMat input = image.getUMat(cv::ACCESS_RW);
_descriptor_calculator.compute(input, descriptor_flat);
```

This works for images with a resolution (up to and including) 2048x1536. However for an image of 2592x1936 I get an unhandled exception, and my debugger breaks in gshandlereh.c.

```
GSUnwindInfo = *(PULONG)GSHandlerData;
if (IS_DISPATCHING(ExceptionRecord->ExceptionFlags)
        ? (GSUnwindInfo & UNW_FLAG_EHANDLER)
        : (GSUnwindInfo & UNW_FLAG_UHANDLER))
{
    Disposition = __CxxFrameHandler3(    // <--------- breaks here
                        ExceptionRecord,
                        EstablisherFrame,
                        ContextRecord,
                        DispatcherContext
                        );
}
else
{
    Disposition = ExceptionContinueSearch;
}
```

Two important points to mention:

1. I can fix the error by downsampling the image, so it appears to be related to the size of the image
2. The CPU version of the code works just fine with 2592x1936 images, so I'm reasonably confident that there isn't an error with any of the input parameters

Downsampling larger images is my fallback option, but I find the conclusion that the OpenCL version of the HOG descriptor compute function can't handle images beyond a certain size a bit unsatisfactory - the fact that there is an unhandled exception rather than an assert and a sensible error message leads me to believe it is more complicated/sinister than this..!

Thanks in advance

Can anybody shed any light on this? Any input would be appreciated.

EDIT:

As requested, a self-contained example. I was able to reproduce the problem by feeding in a random google image that was big enough (searched for jpgs of size 2592x1936):

```
cv::UMat img = cv::imread("image3.jpg", cv::IMREAD_COLOR).getUMat(cv::ACCESS_RW);

uint16_t image_width = img.cols;
uint16_t image_height = img.rows;
int down_scale = 1;

uint16_t _image_width = (uint16_t)ceil((float)(image_width / down_scale) / 16) * 16;
uint16_t _image_height = (uint16_t)ceil((float)(image_height / down_scale) / 16) * 16;

std::cout << _image_height << " x " << _image_width << std::endl;
std::cout << (_image_width - 16) % 16 << std::endl;
std::cout << (_image_height - 16) % 16 << std::endl;

auto descriptor_calculator = cv::HOGDescriptor(cv::Size(_image_width, _image_height), cv::Size(16, 16), cv::Size(16, 16), cv::Size(16, 16), 9);
std::vector<float> descriptor_flat;

descriptor_calculator.compute(img, descriptor_flat);
```

Similar to the original problem, works for small enough images, fails for large enough images. Unfortunately did not manage to glean much more information from running outside of the IDE or setting the IDE to break on all exceptions - the only clue that I've got is that the exception is an access violation. I wondered if it was the call to ceil that was causing an access violation, but the resolution is divisible by 16 so not surprisingly changing to floor made no difference.

Additional info as requested:

- Running in Windows
- Compiler/IDE is Visual Studio 2015
- OpenCV version is 3.4.0

Thanks for the help, happy to provide more info

Comment: Could you provide a proper [mcve] that reproduces it? (You know, for convenience) What platform, compiler and OpenCV version?

Comment: I suggest setting your debugger to break on thrown exceptions to see where the code generating the error is located. Alternatively, depending on platform, running outside the debugger might print that code location to standard error. The code you've shown us appears to be your platform's catch-all exception handler, which is not useful for debugging the problem.